# OAuth2/Azure AD B2C parameters stripped from external web browser in iOS

Tags: react-native, azure-ad-b2c, react-native-ios, appauth

I've developed an application using React Native for Android. Now that I have a mac I am porting the app for iPhone. iPhone seems to work fine except for authentication.

For authentication I'm using React Native App Auth(RNAppAuth) and Azure AD B2C. I went through and setup RNAppAuth as it says to in the documentation for both AppAuth-IOS and RNAppAuth. I believe that everything is setup right for Azure, because it works flawlessly on my Android app.

So here's the problem... When the app goes to login, it attempts to open the authorization page in another browser. I give it this endpoint (NOTE: I replaced my domain with example just for this)...

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/example.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SigninSignup1
```

I get this prompt...

[image]

When I click *Continue* it navigates to a generic Microsoft login instead of the one I specify with my policy parameter `p=B2C_1_SigninSignup1`. In fact, all parameters are stripped it seems, and I'm presented with a login form that does not accept any credentials I have previously setup.

I have found very little about this online, so have come to you guys for help.

Has anyone come across this? If so, how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact problem here, but you can consult following

- Microsoft App Center allows you to use Reactive native Auth with AADB2C using a SDK. You can see the instructions here - 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/auth/react-native. I think the SDK is also public, so you can take a look at the code.
- Another solution from git repo https://github.com/sonyarouje/react-native-ad-b2c

Also please use b2clogin.com. The url you are using is on path of deprecation. Read [here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin)

Comment: Yes, I learned about this today! It still does the prompt, but it at least goes to the correct login screen and I'm able to completely login now. I also changed my authentication endpoint as you suggested, Thanks!